# Telerik : radgrid onItemDatabound event

Tags: telerik-grid, itemtemplate

We have a RadGrid with some telerik:GridTemplateColumns. We get a datasource and bind the grid. For first page grid behavour is consistent. But after page change, other columns in grid gets new values but itemtemplate columns persist the values from first page.

Grid Design Code :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgvTest" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="false"
                                            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" MasterTableView-ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="false"
                                            AllowCustomPaging="false" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="false" AllowMultiRowSelection="true"
                                            AutoGenerateEditColumn="false" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True" OnItemDataBound="rgvTest_ItemDataBound"
                                            OnPageIndexChanged="rgvTest_PageIndexChanged" OnSortCommand="rgvTest_SortCommand"
                                            ClientSettings-ClientEvents-OnRowDblClick="GridRowDoubleclick" >

<Columns>
                                                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" ItemStyle-Width="20px" HeaderStyle-Width="20px"/>
                                                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderImageUrl="../Images/priority_icon.png" UniqueName="Priority1"
                                                        HeaderTooltip="Priority">
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="20px" Wrap="false" />
                                                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px" Wrap="false" />
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Image ID="PriorityImage" runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Considering page size is set to 10.
After debugging , i got that OnItemdataBound event is called for first 10 records on load.
And after page change, it is called for 20 times but insted for 20 record of first page and second page, it is called twice for first 10 records... Strange but true. 
If anyone has any idea abot this please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution. Actually while binding the items we were using Item.ItemIndex property instaed of Item.dataIndex. ItemIndex value varies from 0-10 and DataIndex varies from 0 - length of DataIndex...

Comment: 0 -1o ( Where 10 is page size..)